# Don't know any good teacher recommendations

Tags: recommendation-letter, internship

I am currently applying for an informal(?) internship at my school and the employer asked if I knew any faculty or staff members well enough to write me a recommendation. I have only just completed freshmen year and don't really know any of the teachers well and long enough that I'd be comfortable asking for a recommendation. My math professor did write me a short informal recommendation when I applied to be a math TA, but I don't believe we're close enough for him to write one for an internship.

Should I take a risk and ask my math professor or just tell the employer that I don't know anyone well enough?

Background info about math professor: I had him for two semesters and would go to his office hours maybe 3-4 times a semester to ask questions or just talk about math. Not sure if this is enough though to constitute him as a good recommender.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [How can I get a reference letter if I was never “close” to any professors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82532/how-can-i-get-a-reference-letter-if-i-was-never-close-to-any-professors)

Answer (score 5):

You do what you can. Having someone with a positive opinion of you is probably much better than having no one. There isn't a lot they can say, possibly, but for this it probably isn't critical.

But as you go along, make sure you develop some relationships so that this doesn't arise when it *is* critical.

If he was your supervisor for the TA then he probably has a good enough idea. But if it was another, you might look to them, also.

Comment: Also: faculty are accustomed to this type of request and are able to write basic letters even when they do not necessarily know the student well (but have a generically  good opinion of the student).

Answer (score 2):

If you have excellent grades on the courses he/she teaches and show good attitudes and abilities while working as TA, then I think it is totally possible.

You probably only need your math professor to write a single letter for one employer, so that won't bother him/her too much.